# Login autocomplete keyboard bar appearing regardless of input type in iOS 11.3 WKWebView

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Since iOS 11.3, [which enabled the keychain/login autocomplete within webviews](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208067), the login autocomplete bar (this thing):
[image]
is appearing at unexpected times in WKWebViews.
Specifically, once a password input (or anything detected as a login form) is focused and the bar is displayed once, the bar will display when any other (non-login/password) inputs are focused until the app is (soft or hard) closed and reopened.

Not only does it appear at inappropriate times, the keychain bar actually appears instead of proper autocomplete bar for text inputs, so this is a bit of a UX nightmare where Ionic/Cordova is concerned.

I realise there's an argument for this being a problem with Apple's implementation of this new feature, but I wondered if there is an Ionic/Cordova way around this?

The issue can be reproduced by cloning, building and running (on iOS 11.3) the following repo: https://github.com/johnmap/ionic-ios-keychain-nightmare

I've tried a few things, such as triggering a page refresh, URL change or form submission after the login form is dismissed – no luck with any of these. I'm aware of hacks that prevent the login autofill appearing in the first place – it would of course be preferable to have a solution that maintains the autofill functionality when it's appropriate.

I’ve tried to provide all relevant info – please do let me know if I’ve missed anything. Thank you!

ionic info output:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v9.11.1
npm        : 5.6.0 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145 
Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : not set
Misc:

backend : pro
```